# Find $F = \mathbb Z_3[x] /f(x)$ elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Definition: $\operatorname{char}(R)$ be defined as in this [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_(algebra)).

**NOTE**: We drop the '$[]$'.

Consider $\mathbb Z_3 = \{0, 1, 2\} = \{0, 1, -1\}$ and $g(x) = x^2 + x - 1 \in\mathbb Z_3[x]$.

Explain why $F$ is a field, with 9 elements and find the elements. Furthermore find $char(F)$.

Can anybody show be how to do this? I am honestly note quite sure. To find the elements of $F$ do I compute $x^i$'s where $i= 0, 1,\dots$ stopping when $x^i = 1$ After $ i >0$.

If anybody could help me with this I am kind of just not understanding right now :(.

Comment: **Hint :** Show first that $g$ is irreducible. Then try to understand why this implies that $F$ is a field. Then see why $F$ is an extension of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ of degree $2$, and find a basis of $F$ over $\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: Do you know how $\Bbb R$ is extended by a (nonexistent) root of $x^2+1$? The same goes here with $\Bbb Z_3$ in place of $\Bbb R$ and $g(x)$ in place of $x^2+1$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe, I show the first by show the $g(x) \ne 0$ where $x = 0,1,2$, this is easily done. But I am still unsure of how this would imply $F$ is a field. Is there something I am not understanding?

Comment: @Berci, I am not super familiar with that. Is there a reference you can refer?

Comment: @Seong Well, try to show that if $P$ denotes a polynomial, then $\mathbb{Z}_3[X]/(P)$ is a field iff $P$ is irreducible.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Ah theorem. Ok, now how do I compute the elements of $F$?

Comment: Have you heard about *complex numbers*? It's just that: we introduce a solution $i$ to $x^2+1=0$ and extend the real numbers to include all $a+bi$ with $a,b\in\Bbb R$. Whenever you are about to calculate $i^2$ just use that $i^2+1=0$. Same goes here but with the squaring rule $x^2=1-x$.

Comment: @Berci, Oh yes, I am sorry, the language that you used threw me off a bit. But yes, I am somewhat familiar with the complex number system.

Comment: What is $F$? \:\

Comment: What do you mean @markvs?

Comment: "Explain why $F$ is a field". First explain what is $F$. It is not defined in the Q.

Comment: @markvs It's in the title.

Comment: Then what is $/f(x)$?

Comment: @markvs Even if the question has several problems of notations, it is quite clear that $f=g$ and that $F$ is the quotient by the ideal generated by $f$.

Comment: @TheSilverQue: I repeat the question: what is $/f$ or $/g$ if you prefer.

Comment: @markvs $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(f)$ denotes the quotient of $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ by the ideal generated by $f$. To learn about quotients, you can see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring

Comment: Pleae read my question

Comment: @marks What is your problem ? That the parenthesis are missing ? That the OP should have written $/(f)$ and not $/f$ ? Come on, the question is poorly stated, but what the OP wants is really clear for anyone who knows a very little bit about finite fields.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your question is in the title and by $g(x)$ you are actually referring to $f(x)$.

As per the comments, I believe that you have shown that $f(x)$ does not have any roots in $\mathbb{Z_3}$, i.e. $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z_3[x]}$. As TheSilverDoe pointed out, this "trick" of checking irreducibility by checking if the roots lie in the underlying field is typically applicable only for lower degree polynomials(in general, for degree $3$ or less). An irreducible polynomial by definition does not have any proper divisors, i.e. does not factor into two lower degree non-constant polynomials. For polynomials of degrees $2$ or $3$, one can easily verify that a polynomial is irreducible iff it has no root in the underlying field(i.e has a linear polynomial as a proper factor). This cannot be applied in general, for polynomials of degrees greater than $4$. For example $(x^2+1)^2$ has no root in $\mathbb{R[x]}$ but is reducible as it has $(x^2+1)$ as a proper factor.

Note that $\mathbb{Z_3[x]}$ is a PID since $\mathbb{Z_3}$ is a field(polynomial ring in one variable of a field is a PID). So, all non-zero irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{Z_3[x]}$ in fact generate maximal ideals.
Now again as per the comments, I believe that you have shown the result that $I$ is a maximal ideal of a ring R iff $R/I$ is a field. So we have that $F=\mathbb{Z_3[x]}/(f(x))$ is a field.

In case you are familiar with the notion of field extensions, you'll immediately realize that $F=\mathbb{Z_3[x]}/(f(x)) \cong \mathbb{Z_3}(\alpha)$, where $\alpha=\bar{x}=$Image of $x$ in the homomorphism $\mathbb{Z_3[x]} \to \mathbb{Z_3[x]}/(f(x))= x+(x^2+x-1)$ is a root of $f(x)$ in $F$, i.e. $\alpha^2+\alpha-1=0$

The elements of $\mathbb{Z_3}(\alpha)$, the field extension of $\mathbb{Z_3}$ with $\alpha$ are $\{0,1,2,\alpha,\alpha+1,\alpha+2,2\alpha,2\alpha+1,2\alpha+2\}$.This is the smallest field containing $\mathbb{Z_3}$ and $\alpha$. You can verify that this satisfies all the properties of a field, contains $\mathbb{Z_3}$ and $\alpha$ and has no "unnecessary" elements(i.e. the smallest such field). You would have to simplify some of the terms, keeping in mind that we are in $\mathbb{Z_3}$ and the relation $\alpha^2+\alpha-1=0$). This shows that $F \cong \mathbb{Z_3}(\alpha)$ has $9$ elements.

Comment: The sentence "$f(x)$ does not have any root in $\mathbb{Z}_3$, i.e. $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_3$" is dangerous : you should add that this is only true because $f$ has degree $2$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Yes ofcourse! Thanks for pointing that out!